# How to disable all caps menu titles in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I assume the title is self explanatory. Just want to change the look of the Visual Studio 2012 not to show  menu title in all capital letters.

Comment: If you have a large widescreen monitor with a very high resolution to maximize the amount of code you can see, the all caps menu is actually quite nice. Different strokes for different folks I guess.

Comment: I've posted the workaround (for regedit and PowerShell) to https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/775717/do-not-use-cap-i-tal-let-ters-for-menu-headers#tabs

Comment: Looks like they are reverting to title case in Visual Studio 14 and making this an environment option in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3. http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2837384-change-all-caps-menu-in-vs-2012-to-vs-beta-format

Comment: for newer versions (like Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 or probably VS 2015) there is an option for this. go to `Tools > Options > Environment` and select `Turn off upper case in the menu bar` option

Answer (score 621, accepted):

[Richard Banks posted](http://www.richard-banks.org/2012/06/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-2012-all.html) about a registry key for just such a tweak.

#### Visual Studio 2012 (Full)

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\General
DWORD: SuppressUppercaseConversion
Value: 1
```

In PowerShell, you can run this to set that registry key and the uppercase goes away.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\General -Name SuppressUppercaseConversion -Type DWord -Value 1
```

#### Visual Studio Express 2012

The above registry key is not the one that will affect Visual Studio Express 2012 RC. A [comment by FormatC](http://www.richard-banks.org/2012/06/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-2012-all.html#comment-510984742703194994) showed up on Banks post about the key for Express. You can find that key mentioned in [Mike Gleason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10906509/48700) or run the following PowerShell command to set it.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VSWinExpress\11.0\General -Name SuppressUppercaseConversion -Type DWord -Value 1
```

#### Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VWDExpress\11.0\General -Name SuppressUppercaseConversion -Type DWord -Value 1
```

#### Visual Studio 2013

Replace `11.0` with `12.0` in the registry keys above.

#### Visual Studio 2015 Developer Preview

Replace `11.0` with `14.0` in the registry keys above.

Comment: And it's probably obvious, but for VS Express 2012 **for Web**, use VWDExpress instead of VSWinExpress.

Comment: For VS Express 2012 for Windows Desktop, use WDExpress instead of VSWinExpress

Comment: For cmd: `reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\General /v SuppressUppercaseConversion /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`

Comment: Note: Adding SuppressUppercaseConversion worked for me, except I had to chose 32-bit even though I have a 64-bit system.

Comment: Why... just why did we need SHOUTING capital letters in all new MS products?

Comment: On VS Express 2013 Desktop I had to use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\12.0\General`

Comment: Note that Visual Studio 2015 release candidate has Title case by default.

Comment: If you're like me in that you liked the all-capital menu case, you can restore it in VS2017 by un-ticking Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General -> "Apply ttitle case styling to menu bar".

Answer (score 67):

I have written an extension which will do this for you.

You can download it from the Visual Studio Gallery:

- [VSCommands for Visual Studio 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a83505c6-77b3-44a6-b53b-73d77cba84c8)
- [VSCommands for Visual Studio 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6d1c265-7007-405c-a68b-5606af238ece)

It can also hide main menu altogether and have it appear only on mouse over or alt key press (like in IE)

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: [This Hide Main Menu extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdbcffca-32a6-4034-8e89-c31b86ad4813/) is extremely light-weight, if you don't want all the functionality that VSCommands gives you.

Comment: @Jarrod Dixon Hide Main Menu doesn't change letter case so it is not really useful and even with menu hidden it can only show it with keyboard shortcut and does not support mouse...

Comment: while VSCommands has some great features, which I use often, the way it implements the 'Sentence Case' is somewhat buggy. Eg the ".NET Reflector" menu gets rewritten as ".net reflector", all lowercase. So imo the registry key is still the way to go even if you use VSCommands.

Comment: @stijn great find about the sentence case issue, thanks for that. It should be fixed in latest build https://dl.dropbox.com/u/65031070/SquaredInfinity.VSCommands.VS11.2.0.5.vsix It will also be availabe from Visual Studio Gallery soon.

Comment: When you recommend an off-site resource, you need to disclose your relationship to it.  Even if the cost is $0.

Comment: The biggest problem with the extension approach, is that it can't be used in the Express versions of Visual Studio. They don't seem to allow the addition of extensions.

I opted for the Kevin Symth approach: 

reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\General /v SuppressUppercaseConversion /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

Worked fine for me. You'd have to change it for each of the various versions of VS ...

Answer (score 57):

After years Microsoft has changed their mind on this feature. As of Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 RC, an option has been added to change between mixed case and upper case: *Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Turn off upper case in the menu bar*
Obviously this is not for VS 2012 but going forward this option will be there.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/07/02/vs-tfs-2013-3-update-3-rc.aspx) is the notification from Brian Harry of Microsoft:

> Mixed Case Menus – I know I’m going to get some feedback on this one :)  This is a long standing request by a vocal portion of the VS user base since VS 2012 to change the “ALL CAPS” menus.  In VS 2013 Update 3, we have added a Tools –> Options setting to control whether you see ALL CAPS or Mixed Case.  The default is still ALL CAPS but, if you change it, it will persist across upgrades and will roam across your IDE instances using the VS Online roaming settings feature (if you log into VS so it knows who you are).

Comment: In 2014 CTP2 it is set by default to Mixed Caps :D It seems, that the feedback done what it should. Now waiting to remove this option at all from VS. It seems, that Microsoft *again* will have to learn the "don't fix it if it ain't broken" rule...

Comment: @Spook i prefer the all caps menus myself.  What harm is there in leaving the option that you feel it needs to be removed?

Comment: I was refering to the idea of making menu titles ALL CAPS in the first place.

Comment: @Andy I was originally mildly irritated at the all-caps menus, got used to it years ago, just happened across this (wasn't really looking for it), implemented it and I'm almost stunned at how friggin' strongly I prefer the mixed-case menus. So I'm firmly in the camp of leave it alone if it isn't broken (by which, like Spook, I mean they shouldn't have made the menus all-caps in the first place, nobody was asking for that).

Comment: @Craig That's fine, but they did change it, got blowback and made it configurable, so why not leave it where it is now and give users a choice?

Comment: @Andy I suppose they will. I'm just adding my voice to the giant chorus saying that in general, when things aren't broken, don't screw with them. Fix the broken stuff. There are plenty of broken things to play with.

Comment: @Craig So they shouldn't have changed themes, i mean the vs2005 theme worked, so why change it.  I'm going to disagree with you that they only change "broken" things.

Comment: @Andy I'm okay with you disagreeing. :-)  They also forced the Windows 8 full-screen "metro" UI down everybody's throats and that has been pretty much universally rejected. Windows 8.x was not a success and nobody used "modern UI" apps. Now, modern UI apps on Windows 10 are in resizable windows and it's possible to side-load them. Regardless, I can't think of too many reasons to develop Windows Store apps for business. When 98% of the market hates something you did, it's a clear sign you shouldn't have done it and shouldn't do it again. Peace.  ;-)

Comment: In VS 2015 Community, this setting is where it's described in the answer but it's called "Apply title case styling to menu bar."

Comment: In VS 2017, it's also called "Apply title case styling to menu bar".

Answer (score 15):

And for

**Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop**

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\11.0\General
DWORD: SuppressUppercaseConversion
Value: 1
```

I guess the reason MS omitted any mention of Visual Studio from the keyname is that such a mention might help someone identify the key :)

Answer (score 12):

The VS Commands extension can do this and is one of the most popular on the gallery. Worth checking out!

[image]

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a83505c6-77b3-44a6-b53b-73d77cba84c8?SRC=VSIDE

Answer (score 8):

Now that Visual Studio 2015 has changed the default back to Title Case, for those crazies like me who had gotten used to ALL CAPS, you can change it back by **disabling** the following option:

- Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Apply title case styling to menu bar

Comment: Same for vs 2017

Answer (score 8):

**Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition** does not respond to the SuppressUppercaseConversion registry value.

The answer is to **enable** the option boflynn identified:

• **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Environment** -> **General** -> **Apply title case styling to menu bar**

In my case that setting was not on by default, perhaps since I ported my VS 2013 settings.

-Noel

Answer (score 7):

For express use:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSWinExpress\11.0\GeneralSuppressUppercaseConversion
```

Credit to [FormatC](http://www.richard-banks.org/2012/06/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-2012-all.html)

Answer (score 6):

I have been using the following reg files to enable/disable the lowercasing in Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013:

http://erwinmayer.com/dl/VS2012_ALLCAPS_Toggle.zip
http://erwinmayer.com/dl/VS2013_ALLCAPS_Toggle.zip

Just double click on `VS201x_ALLCAPS_Disable.reg` inside the archive to disable all caps menu titles, and `VS201x_ALLCAPS_Enable.reg` to re-enable them.

You can easily edit the reg files before with a text editor to see what they contain.

Comment: The only solution worked for my premium version. Lost half an hour for solving this...

Comment: As with Alex, this is the only solution that worked me - I have Premium as well.

Comment: Make sure there's no space following SuppressUppercaseConversion if you're not using the .reg file!

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone, use

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VPDExpress\11.0\General\SuppressUppercaseConversion
```

Answer (score 1):

I think **"VSCommands for Visual Studio 2012"** is the best option for this.

Grab this plugin from here: 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a83505c6-77b3-44a6-b53b-73d77cba84c8

Answer (score 1):

**Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019**

Check the option `Apply title case styling to menu bar`

which can be found in `Tools > Options > Environment > General`