# Can you turn off all caps on the menus in VS2012?

Tags: ide, menubar, visual-studio-2012

The all caps in the menus for VS2012 is highly annoying, is there a setting somewhere in the IDE or elsewhere to turn it off?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable all caps menu titles in Visual Studio 2012 RC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859173/how-to-disable-all-caps-menu-titles-in-visual-studio-2012-rc)

Comment: I agree, it is duplicate, but why did that not show up when I searched and when I put in the question title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes; search NuGet (yes, NuGet) for [VS2012 Caps](http://nuget.org/packages/VS2012.RemoveAllCaps).

Answer (score 37):

There is also another way to do this, create the following registry key and set its value:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\General\SuppressUppercaseConversion
REG_DWORD value: 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct Ajay - VS2012 does seem to store it's settings in the registry location mentioned above (it worked for me anyway)

Answer (score 9):

You can also run this in the Power Shell

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\General -Name SuppressUppercaseConversion -Type DWord -Value 1
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way (IMO) to achieve the registry key suggested by [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11053386/422877) would be entering it through a registry-file.  This can be done by saving the code underneath to a `.reg`-file (e.g. `VS2012_MenuCasing.reg`) and double-clicking it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\General\]
"SuppressUppercaseConversion"=dword:00000001
```

I hope it saves somebody some time...