# Icons in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2012 with Visual Studio Icon Patcher

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have tried Visual Studio Icon Patcher, and install NiceVS.0.8.1.1 Beta.Full. But the icnos are still in VS2012 style, see

[image]

My installation is : VS2012 -> VS2012 Update 1 -> VSIP -> NiceVS.
I also tried : VS2012 -> VSIP -> NiceVS (no Update 1).

The "Images" folder I got after extract has 189 files (1521834 bytes).

Any idea why the icons in solution explorer is not changed? Any way to fix this or any other way to change the icons in solution explorer?

Comment: This new design is non-sense for me. I can't not even imagine why they want to use CAPITAL MENU NAMES!

Comment: We can't discuss a "chat" topic here, otherwise I really have a question in mind: Why the big companies or some big project would introduce ugly and non-senese new UI. VS2012 is an example, and Adobe 10 is another example!

Comment: Disable capitals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859173/how-to-disable-all-caps-menu-titles-in-visual-studio-2012-rc

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks, but I know it. My problem is the icons in solution explorer.