# Usual methods to get rid of all caps menu on Visual Studio Express 2012 have failed. Please advise

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ide, registry, visual-studio-express, visual-studio-extensions

I've been trying to get rid of the all caps menu in VS express for desktop but to no avail. I've tried the usual registry hack by putting this into powershell

`Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\General -Name SuppressUppercaseConversion -Type DWord -Value 1`

But there is no `General` folder contained in the `11.0` folder, so that option fails.

I've also tried to install an extension that allows you to turn off all caps 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a83505c6-77b3-44a6-b53b-73d77cba84c8
but that just fails to install with the error `VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException:...`

So. As small a problem as this is, it is *really* annoying me that I can't do anything about it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What edition of VS2012?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859173/how-to-disable-all-caps-menu-titles-in-visual-studio-2012-rc#comment16692218_10859562), the key would be HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\11.0\General.

Comment: Solved! Thank you Jason :)