# Disable ALL CAPS menu items in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013, Microsoft again presents the menu in UPPERCASE as the default.

Can these be modified to be Sentence Case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable all caps menu titles in Visual Studio 2012 RC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859173/how-to-disable-all-caps-menu-titles-in-visual-studio-2012-rc)

Comment: @stonemetal the procedure w/2012 is similar, but different in details. There should be a wiki covering all versions. This is what I intended.

Comment: Not a dupe, the accepted answer to the other question does not work here!

Comment: It's the same in VS 2013 RC. Also same solution works for this.

Comment: I've posted the workaround (for regedit and PowerShell) to https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/775717/do-not-use-cap-i-tal-let-ters-for-menu-headers#tabs

Comment: Microsoft sure are clueless when it comes to interface design. Who thought doing this in all caps was a good idea?!?

Comment: @Almo, I know I'm late to the party here, but I did. I liked them, and was rather disappointed to see that they'd disappeared when I installed VS2017. Fortunately, there is now a simple configuration option to turn them on and off, under Tools - Options - General. (Or TOOLS - Options - General, in my case :-))

Answer (score 368, accepted):

Yes - in the new **Visual Studio 2013** (as in VS 2012), MS reinforced their design decision to make ALL CAPS MENU ITEMS the default. The methods for reverting the menu style are almost the same methods used for Visual Studio 2012, [which has been discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859173/how-to-disable-all-caps-menu-titles-in-visual-studio-2012-rc).

---

**Update** (after Visual Studio 2013 Update 4)

As of Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 you can go into *Tools > Options > Environment*
 and uncheck *Turn off upper case in the menu bar* 
[image: screenshot of the menu]

---

**Before** Visual Studio 2013 Update 4:

You need to create a specific registry key if you want "old-style" menus back.

---

**First Variant**: Since *Package Manager Console* is [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx), select menu options **TOOLS** / **Library Package Manager** / **Package Manager Console** and enter and run

`Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\General -Name SuppressUppercaseConversion -Type DWord -Value 1`
(as a single line).

---

**Second Variant**: Open up a Command Prompt (<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, `cmd`, <kbd>enter</kbd>) and enter and run

`REG ADD HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\General /v SuppressUppercaseConversion /t REG_DWORD /d 1`
(as a single line).

---

**Third Variant**:
Change registry values by hand, open `regedit` and navigate to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\General
```

then, create (right click):

```
 DWORD value
```

with the content of

```
 SuppressUppercaseConversion
```

and set it to

```
 1
```

Close regedit.exe and you're done.

---

**Fourth Variant**: At least one VS Extension (**[VSCommands for Visual Studio 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6d1c265-7007-405c-a68b-5606af238ece)**) has been published that enables you (among other things) **to switch menu style via config menu** from within VS 2013.

You may also set it to **all-lower-case** items (which is, imho, nice):
[image]

switch to **Sentence Case** (subtly different from what you get with SuppressUppercaseConversion: the SQL menu gets renamed to Sql)
[image]

or **hide it completely** (and have it appear on ALT key press or mouse over)
[image]

Comment: `+1` for the Power Shell version!

Comment: The full path for VS Commands is `Tools > VSCommands > Options > IDE Enhancements > Main Menu > Check "Change Main Menu letter case"` and select your preference.

Comment: [ctl] + [r] should be [win] + [r]. ``cmd``, [enter]

Comment: Note: The `Package Manager Console` in VS.NET is actually a Powershell command window so those familiar with using it for NuGet can paste the 1st option in from above, run, restart VS.NET and it works like a charm.

Comment: if I could +1 it more than once.

Comment: This is a wonderful answer but with the full release of Update 3 and 4 it is no longer the best approach. It is much easier to use the Tools > Options approach described by @ScottWylie.

Comment: make sure to change 12.0 to 11.0 if using VS 2012

Answer (score 43):

After years Microsoft has changed their mind on this feature. As of Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 RC, an option has been added in Tools -> Options to change to Mixed Case for Menu titles. Obviously this is not for VS 2012 but going forward this option will be there.

Here is the notification from Brian Harry of Microsoft....

> Mixed Case Menus – I know I’m going to get some feedback on this one :) This is a long standing request by a vocal portion of the VS user base since VS 2012 to change the “ALL CAPS” menus. In VS 2013 Update 3, we have added a Tools –> Options setting to control whether you see ALL CAPS or Mixed Case. The default is still ALL CAPS but, if you change it, it will persist across upgrades and will roam across your IDE instances using the VS Online roaming settings feature (if you log into VS so it knows who you are).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/07/02/vs-tfs-2013-3-update-3-rc.aspx

Comment: I'm running VS2013 and can't find the option anywhere in Tools -> Options.  I'm guessing I can't see the wood for the trees so could someone point out which section it is under?

Comment: Make sure you install VS 2013 Update 3 RC first.  It is under Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General.  It is right under the Color Theme option.

Comment: Now that Update 3 and 4 are RTM the accepted answer really should be this one as having the other valid and worthwhile answer that requires registry hacks or 3rd party extensions marked as accepted is leading people in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 9):

I have been using the following reg files to enable/disable the lowercasing in Visual Studio 2013:

http://erwinmayer.com/dl/VS2013_ALLCAPS_Toggle.zip

Just double click on `VS2013_ALLCAPS_Disable.reg` inside the archive to disable all caps menu titles, and `VS2013_ALLCAPS_Enable.reg` to re-enable them.

You can easily edit the reg files before with a text editor to see what they contain.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using the "Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop" version the registry key should be added in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\12.0\General
```

Comment: Or for command prompt users: `REG ADD HKCU\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\12.0\General /v SuppressUppercaseConversion /t REG_DWORD /d 1` (all on one line)

Answer (score 5):

So simple! You can go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General tab and check the **Turn off uppercase checkbox** from the right side and click ok. Visual studio 2013 will automatically turn off uppercasing of the menubar.

Answer (score 3):

1. VS 2013:
   Tools→Extensions and Updates→Online,
   Type "VSCommands" in search textbox,
   Click Download
2. Tools→Options→VSCommands→General,
   Click Open-Configuration button
3. IDEEnhancements→Main Menu→Change Main Menu Letter Case,
   click Sentence-Case